# CSV export error in Netlogo

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, netlogo

I'm trying to export list data to CSV file.

```
csv:to-file "myfile.csv" [[1 "two" 3] [4 5]]
```

This one is working.

```
set mylist [ "apple" "book" ]
csv:to-file "myfile.csv" mylist
```

But this one is not working.
It shows scala.MatchError: apple (of class java.lang.String)
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The [`csv:to-file`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/csv.html#csv:to-file) reporter is expecting a list of lists, representing a list of rows where each row is itself represented as a list.

Even if you only have one row, you still need to pass a list of list. So instead of:

```
set mylist ["apple" "book"]
csv:to-file "myfile.csv" mylist
```

you should do:

```
set mylist [["apple" "book"]]
csv:to-file "myfile.csv" mylist
```

(Notice the double brackets.)

That being said, I think you're using an older version of the extension, because you should not be seeing a Scala runtime error (I think you're running into [this issue](https://github.com/NetLogo/CSV-Extension/issues/9).) If you upgrade to NetLogo 6.0.2 and use the bundled version of the extension, you'll get a much clearer message:

```
Extension exception: Expected a list of lists, but apple was one of the elements.
error while observer running CSV:TO-FILE
  called by procedure SETUP
  called by Command Center
```